# How to change Keycloak loginId using Keycloak REST APIs

Tags: security, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to change the Keycloak user loginId using Keycloak REST APIs. My Keycloak version is 4.4.0 According to the documentation first I need to set `"editUsernameAllowed": "true"` in RealmRepresentation before updating the user. I am calling this PUT API `http://localhost:8081/auth/admin/realms/{myrealm}`.

But I am really disappointed with the request body because the Keyclaok documentation is not clear. I tried as follows with the token. But it won't work.

```
{
    "rep":{
        "editUsernameAllowed": "true"
    }
}
```

```
{
    "editUsernameAllowed": "true"
}
```

May I know the correct way to do this?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @RiteshPuj In first case it says `Unrecognized field &quot;rep&quot; (class org.keycloak.representations.idm.RealmRepresentation), not marked as ignorable`. Second case it returns 403

Comment: I have added a answer. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @RiteshPuj I checked, but it also returns 403

Comment: can you please publish the curl request that you are using to call the API? Maybe you are missing the token in the request.

Comment: I am trying using Postman, I have already added the bearer token in the header as well.

Comment: the error 403 forbidden suggests that the token or credentials that you are using doesn't have enough privileges to update the realm. can you please check on this part?

Comment: ok. I'll check this. Thanks, much.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string value to the field `editUsernameAllowed`, but it accepts a boolean value. Try this:

`http://localhost:8081/auth/admin/realms/{myrealm}`
Body:

```
{
    "editUsernameAllowed": true
}
```

Comment: Here is my request `PUT /auth/admin/realms/api HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <token>
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.17.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 5e3d975e-4880-4973-9dee-586008362d64,8a2acc48-e31e-4fb6-8bec-90e1e5057e7e
Host: localhost:8081
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 32
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

{
 "editUsernameAllowed": true
}`